# iOS and php currency converter

Tags: php

php currency converter , used to work fine

```
function get_currency($from_Currency, $to_Currency, $amount) {
$amount = urlencode($amount);
$from_Currency = urlencode($from_Currency);
$to_Currency = urlencode($to_Currency);

$url = "http://www.google.com/finance/converter?a=$amount&from=$from_Currency&to=$to_Currency";

$ch = curl_init();
$timeout = 0;
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT,
             "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.1)");
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $timeout);
$rawdata = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
$data = explode('bld>', $rawdata);
$data = explode($to_Currency, $data[1]); // line 21

return round($data[0], 2);
```

}

now i get this error

> **Notice**:  Undefined offset: 1 in
>   **/storage/ssd1/708/2065708/public_html/function.php** on line
>   **21**

Comment: `var_dump($data);` It sounds like if there's an array, it's either empty or only has one item in it (key 0)

Comment: Output has probably changed and ```explode('bld>', $rawdata)``` is not exploding returning an array containing only one element - that's why you get error about not existent offset 1 on the next line

Answer (score 0):

This line will explode the contents of `$rawdata` to an array.

```
$data = explode('bld>', $rawdata);
```

But if `$rawdata` does not contain 'bld>', then the entire string will be returned as `$data[0]` and there will be no `$data[1]`. Hence the error `Undefined  offset: 1`.

You could check if `$rawdata` actually contains 'bld>' with

```
if (substr_count($rawdata,'bld>')==0) {
  //do something else
  return;
}

//your current code
```

But it depends on what you expect from `get_currency($from_Currency, $to_Currency, $amount)`. If you should always get the currency, [throw an error](http://php.net/manual/en/internals2.opcodes.throw.php), but if you want to check the result elsewhere, you could just return nothing `return;` or `return NULL;`

Checking you link it does seem to include `bld>`, but it will probably show something different with certain criteria. So check what you enter when the function fails and open the `url` in a browser and check the source. You'll notice the `<span class=bld>***</span>` is missing. This does happen when you send the same currency as `from` and `to`.

Comment: i changed the link to http://finance.google.com/finance/converter and worked like before.

Comment: Just try with the same value for `$from_Currency` and `$to_Currency` and you'll see that it still fails sometimes. But the link you used does redirect to the base page and that does not include `bld>`, so that would fail indeed.